# Eclipse - SQL Results view - Print SQLWarnings

Tags: sql, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sybase

In Eclipse, with the help of Data Source Explorer I am able to connect to Sybase successfully. SQL select query results are listed fine.

However, I'm unable to see the output of SQLWarning messages. Eg. Print statements output.

Is there any way to configure the SQL Results view to display SQLWarnings?

[Added on Jun 21, 2018 by TheImpaler]: An important use of SQLWarnings is to display and retrieve execution plans in SAP ASE (ex-Sybase) since it's the only way of getting them through JDBC.

Comment: Check line number 6 of your code it has errors.

Answer (score 1):

There's no option in Eclipse to show the SQL warnings when running SQL statements. It's probably not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Eclipse's Data Source Explorer does not offer any options to show (or to look at) the SQL Warnings.